# TCL script cannot configure multicast socket

Tags: sockets, tcl, multicast, multicastsocket, tclsh

I'm working with tcl script under ubuntu 12.04, and I'm facing some problem when I try to configure a multicast socket. What I'm trying to do is to forward traffic from some socket to a multicast one, but I don't know why although the multicast socket is created well,apparently; it isn't bound to the multicast group I want to.

This is the script I'm using

```
#!/bin/sh
# test.tcl \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

package require udp

set multicastPort "50003"

proc connector {unicastIP multicastIP port {protocol tcp}} {

    if { [string equal $protocol "tcp"] } {

        socket -server serverTCP -myaddr $unicastIP  $port
        puts "tcp"

    } elseif {[string equal $protocol "udp" ] } {
        serverUDP $unicastIP $multicastIP $port
        puts "udp"

    }

}
proc serverUDP {unicastIP multicastIP port} {
    global multicastPort

    set socketUDP [udp_open $port]
    puts " $unicastIP"
    fconfigure $socketUDP -blocking false -translation binary -buffering none -remote [list $unicastIP $port]
    #fileevent $socketUDP readable [list gettingData $socketUDP]

    set multicastSocket [udp_open $multicastPort]
    udp_conf $multicastSocket -ttl 4
    fconfigure $multicastSocket -blocking false -translation binary -buffering none -mcastadd $multicastIP -remote [list $multicastIP $port]
    fileevent $socketUDP readable [list forwarding $socketUDP $multicastSocket ]

    #puts $socketUDP "hello!"
    #flush $socketUDP
}
proc forwarding {socketSrc socketDst} {
    set data [read -nonewline $socketSrc]
    puts "Read data-> $data"
    puts -nonewline $socketDst $data
    puts "Written data-> [read -nonewline $socketDst]"
}
connector 127.0.0.1 224.0.1.1 50000 udp
vwait forever
```

However if I run the script and check out the ports in my system, the multicast port is not assigned the proper multicast IP as you can see

```
~$ netstat -ptnlu
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*                           3334/tclsh      
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50003           0.0.0.0:*                           3334/tclsh
```

Could anyone tell me the reason?

THanks in advance,

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, that is OK. I have a multicast daemon in production using Tcl and its `udp` package, and `netstat` and `ss` tools also show me the socket as listening on the wildcard address.

"The trick" here, I suppose, is that multicasting is one level up the stack: joining a multicast group is not merely opening a socket or an endpoint on the group address but rather sending a very real [`IGMP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGMP) "join" message to the local transport segment (Ethernet, in most deployments) and further communicating with the nearby `IGMP` routers (again, on Ethernet, they're mostly switches).

So, in your case, just fire up `tcpdump` and see what it dumps when you start your program.  A useful call to `tcpdump` looks something like this:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n 'igmp and host 224.0.1.1'
```

To observe UDP traffic exchanges use

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -n 'udp and host 224.0.1.1 and port 50000'
```

Comment: If I run my script and execute either the first or second command, I don't get any kind of output from tcpdump, does it mean that the igmp messages are not sent?

Comment: @ndarkness, if the interface name and the group address are correct, then yes. Try to create a really minimal example first. Another question: are you running a "stock" distro kernel (I mean, are you sure multi casting is enabled)? Examining `/boot/config-$version` for `IGMP` and `multi` may help. Grepping the output of `sysctl -a` is also advised.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hints  doing `cat /boot/config-3.5.0-39-generic | grep IGMP` retrives `CONFIG_BRIDGE_IGMP_SNOOPING=y`. And if I type `sysctl -a | grep igmp` get this `net.ipv4.conf.all.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth2.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.force_igmp_version = 0
net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships = 20
net.ipv4.igmp_max_msf = 10`

Comment: What's more, if I start a vlc multicast streaming locally I can open the multicast stream in the same machien, so I guess that is not a problem of multicast itseld, if a problem of the tcl script...